# Error in using react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using React-bootstrap package on my Keystone.JS project. To test I tried putting a button in my index page. However, I get the following warning:

> **Warning:** Unknown props `bsStyle`, `active`, `block`, `navItem`,
>   `navDropdown`, `bsClass` on  tag. Remove these props from the
>   element.

This is the code where I use `Button`:

```
var React = require('react');
var Layout = require('../../layouts/defaultLayout');
var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
var Button = require('react-bootstrap').Button;

module.exports = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <Button bsStyle="primary">Default button</Button>
        );
    }
});
```

What am I missing? Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1994

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short

Many component libraries (including react-bootstrap see [issue](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1994)) were relying on passing custom properties to DOM elements w/o `data-` prefix.

Starting 15.2.0 React warns about unknown properties on DOM element

> Add warning for unknown properties on DOM elements. (@jimfb in #6800, @gm758 in #7152)

You need to update library. This was fixed in v0.30.0-rc.1.

Comment: Yeah thanks! Actually I saw the action live with my eyes just a while ago (the comments on this issue were as recent as minutes or hours ago).